# order rule execution in parallel make without introducing dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have a project that consists a single target that requires ~30 files of type A, that are handled by one pattern rule, and one different target of type B, that is independent of the other 30. Here's some pseudo-code to show what I have, in a very simplified form:

```
OBJECTS=obj/obj1.o obj/obj2.o ...
SPECIAL=special/specialobj.o

libMyLibrary.so: $(OBJECTS) $(SPECIAL)
    g++ -shared -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.cxx
    g++ -c -fPIC -o $@ $^

$(SPECIAL): special/mySpecialCode.cxx
    g++ -c -fPIC -o $@ $^ -DFANCY_FLAG
```

The makefile works fine, and the dependency resolution is flawless. However, somehow, `make` always decides to build `$(SPECIAL)` last. While this doesn't matter at all, as it works either way, the compilation of `$(SPECIAL)` takes significantly longer than anything else in my case, almost as long as all other objects combined. Hence, it would be nice if one could encourage `make` to start with compiling `$(SPECIAL)`, so that it can be compiled in parallel along the others, which would cut compile time dramatically.

Is it possible to achieve such a thing?

PS: I can live with non-portable versions, as the code is a very dedicated piece of software that will only be compiled and run on a very particular set of machines, the setup of which I know pretty well at development time.

## EDIT

Following up on a comment made me realise that in the case I have shown here, the problem can indeed be solved by simply swapping the order `$(OBJECTS) $(SPECIAL)` to `$(SPECIAL) $(OBJECTS)` - sometimes, it's that simple.

However, in my actual usecase, this does not work, so I have built an MWE that (1) actually works (with gnumake) and is (2)  a little bit closer to how things actually work in my project.
Here, the file that takes so long to compile actually depends on a source file that is only generated in an additional step. You can observe the change in order by swapping the two lines following the comment.

If somebody can provide a way how to fix the behavior also for this case, that would be great!

If it's not possible to change the order to the desired one in this case, I will accept any answer that explains to some details why it's impossible.

```
OBJECTS=obj/obj1.o obj/obj2.o obj/obj3.o obj/obj4.o obj/obj5.o
SPECIAL=special/specialobj.o
SPECIALSRC=special/mySpecialCode.cxx

OBJ_DIR=obj
SPECIAL_DIR=special

all: libMyLibrary

$(SPECIAL_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

libMyLibrary: $(SPECIAL) $(OBJECTS) 
    cat $^ > $@

obj/%.o: | $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo creating $@
    @echo $@ > $@

$(SPECIALSRC): | $(SPECIAL_DIR)
    @echo special > $@

# swap the following two lines to observe the change in ordering
# $(SPECIAL): $(SPECIALSRC) | $(SPECIAL_DIR)
$(SPECIAL): | $(SPECIAL_DIR)
    @echo starting special
    @echo special > $@
    @sleep 1s
    @echo special done

clean:
    rm -rf libMyLibrary $(OBJ_DIR) $(SPECIAL_DIR)
```

Comment: Have you tried `libMyLibrary.so: $(SPECIAL) $(OBJECTS)`?

Comment: This indeed works for the case I have shown - wow. However, it doesn't work for the case I'm actually looking at, which was a bit over-simplified, as it seems, so I've updated my question.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to control the order that make chooses to use. I don't think it is too smart about scheduling though. I imagine it just schedules in order as it can. You might be able to tune the count to `-j` to get the break to work out in your favor or run `make $special all` to get make to start that target first though.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you explain why it is that `make` chooses to build `$special` last, though? It seems like make has an internal queue, and since `$special` gets added last (since its prequisites are met last), it gets built last. Is this what happens internally, or is there more going on?

Comment: I can't say for certain (I don't have a model of make internals strong enough for that) but I would imagine (and the `make -d` output seems to confirm this) that this is more of a tiered system. The prerequisites are run in tiers and adding `$(SPECIALSRC)` to the rule adds a layer of the tree for that path.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2367370/258523) gives a little more detail on what make does (in terms of `-j` but should apply here and mostly matches up with my previous comment).