# Why might a (makefile) build work serially but not in parallel, and would pattern matching cause such an issue?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, parallel-processing, pattern-matching

Essentially, I have a very large project that ordinarily takes an incredible amount of time to build. For this reason, it is much better to use the -j option and divide it into a bunch of jobs, speeding up the process. But it seems that when I do do this, the build will crash at seemingly random times. If I keep trying, eventually the build will work. I am not too experienced with Makefiles (I have worked with them before, but none as large as this), so I am at a loss as to why it fails.

The only thing I can think of as to why this would happen is that the makefile is made almost completely out of pattern based rules. (If I am not using the terminology correctly, I mean a rule that looks like this...)

---

$(OUTDIR)/%.o: $(EXAMPLEDIR)/%.c

...

...

---

So would this result in problems with the -j option? Am I on the right track or am I completely wrong (if so what would cause these types of problems)?

Thank you in advanced for reading this

Comment: What compiler do you use ? I actually use both gcc3 and gcc4, with gcc3 the parallel build fails whereas it works correctly with gcc4. It's a custom cross-compiler but I think the gcc3 one was based on Cygwin. Could you also provide your Makefile ?

Comment: I use version 5.3 of GCC (with Cygwin). Unfortunately, I cannot provide the makefile (company-confidentiality purposes), which I understand may make things more difficult.

Comment: Nobody is asking you for the actual makefile. You need to write a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @2501 Actually the first comment was

Comment: Well that's right but an MCVE will be fine too ! Just the basic structure, the kind of rule and target, not the details and names your company is using. Could you also try with another compiler ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question probably could have been worded better, I am sorry for that. I was trying to ask in a more general/theoretical sense if pattern-rules were considered thread safe, (as I know that the compiler has to figure out dependencies on its own in this case). The reason I spoke so much about the makefile I was working with was because that is what sparked my curiosity, I am asking more in terms of all makefiles that utilize this

Comment: Well I think you should try at least one of these things : 1. Same Makefile and sources, other compiler, or 2. Same compiler, other Makefile and project (i.e. any easy project with very simple and basic Makefile but a dozen source files to compile). Then you'll know if it's a compiler or Makefile issue. Also see this thread and try to relate with your Makefile : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367284/how-does-the-make-j-option-actually-work

Comment: Good idea, I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: When parallel make fails, but works with repeated reruns the most common problem is missing dependencies.  You should try to capture the build error, which probably relates to some dependency not being ready yet.  Then figure out which part of the makefile is consuming the dependency, and which part generates the dependency.  Changing the compiler proves very little.  The failure will almost certainly be a race condition and a slower or faster compiler will simply hide the missing makefile rule

Comment: @Andrew I agree however in my (very specific) case the compiler was the problem. Anyway we have to few details to tell more about the nature of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, make is not multithreaded.  It's single-threaded, it just invokes multiple programs simultaneously to get parallel job support.

The short answer is, no, there's nothing about pattern rules themselves that is problematic for parallel builds.

If your build works serially but fails when run in parallel, and *particularly* if it works if you keep running it over and over, then the only reason for this is that your makefiles are wrong: there are dependencies between one or more of your targets which you haven't encoded in your makefile, so make doesn't know about them, as @Andrew says.

The way to fix it is look at which file failed to compile, and see why it failed (what file was missing that caused the compile failure), then make sure that this file is listed as a prerequisite of the target that need it.  Wash, rinse, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Makefile` fails to build under `-jN`, `N` > 1, it means that it contains race conditions, and is not parallelizable in its current state.

What this means is that the build steps contain hidden inter-dependencies which are not expressed as Make dependencies in the rules.

**Tip:** Sometimes this happens due to assumptions of left-to-right evaluation among the prerequisites of a rule. That is to say:

```
  z: x0 x1 x2 x3
```

Suppose `x2` doesn't correctly build unless `x1` is fully updated, and that is precisely why `x1` appears to the left of `x2`. If such a situation exists, we may be able to inform Make by adding:

```
  x2: x1
```

This is tricky, though, because now if a rebuild of `x2` is happens to be triggered because `x1` is newer, `x1` will appear as the list of prerequisites. That means that when the special `$^` variable is used in the rule that updates `x2`, it potentially contains `x1`. The rules have to avoid this being a problem.

So that's one tool for addressing these hidden dependencies. It's another matter to actually find them. I don't know of any tools which do this automatically. Empirical testing is time consuming; you may find that a build works 19 times and breaks on the 20th attempt. Then the logs are the only clue about what build recipes are racing against each other. (E.g rule X complains that a certain file is not found, and that file is produced by rule Y. Aha, Y must be ordered before X.)

You can inspect a `Makefile` for potential problems. As a rule of thumb "purely functional" build steps aren't a problem: by that I mean build steps which operate on the prerequisites and produce the target.   The problem rules are the ones which have additional effects, such as implicitly depending on files produced by some other rules, where these files are not listed as prerequisites. Or producing additional files in addition to the target (and these additional files are referenced elsewhere).

Example: Yacc implementation produce `y.tab.c` but also a `y.tab.h`. You might have a dependency on `y.tab.h` somewhere, but it's the Yacc rule doesn't encode the fact that it produces `y.tab.h`. It just so happens that in the non-threaded operation of Make, the Yacc rule always gets run first and so `y.tab.h` is there when the other rules fire which need it. And that could happen because of the order of the object files. `fooprog` depends on `y.tab.o` and `main.o`.  And `main.o` depends on `y.tab.h`. But `main.o` is to the right of `y.tab.o`, and `y.tab.h` is implicitly updated whenever `y.tab.o` is updated, because that happens only whenever `y.tab.c` is updated, which regenerates `y.tab.h` also. So `main.o` will sometimes be rebuilt because it is older than `y.tab.h`, but it will never run into the problem that `y.tab.h` is missing and there is "no rule to create target `y.tab.h`".

That problem will be exposed under parallel mode, though, over a clean tree. Make will try to update `y.tab.o` and `main.o` in parallel and, oops, `main.o` depends on `y.tab.h`. `y.tab.h` doesn't exist unless the `y.tab.o` rule wins the race and sneaks it in just before the `main.o` rule processing checks for its existence. And `y.tab.h` not only doesn't exist, but there is no rule to create it.