# Make with the "-j" option: how does Make know when to move ahead in the dependency graph?

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367284/how-does-the-make-j-option-actually-work) describes how `make` builds targets in the correct order. I would like to understand more about the parallelism specifically. From the post:

> Under normal non-parallel operation make will simply pick a single
>   target each iteration and build it. When it is parallel it will grab
>   as many dependency-less targets as it can and build them in parallel,
>   up to the number of permitted simultaneous jobs.

What I picture:

1. Find all the targets with no missing dependencies.
2. Build all those targets.
3. Wait for all the parallel workers to finish (synchronize).
4. Go back to step (1).

But this is wrong: `make -j` somehow knows when to move ahead in the graph without step (3). New targets begin when and only when all the dependencies finish and a parallel worker is available. How?

For example, consider the graph:

```
A -> C
B -> D
```

In my first guess, `make -j2` would wait for *both* `A` and `B` to finish before *either* `C` or `D` begins. However, it seems to know it can move on to `C` if `A` finishes but `B` is still in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally make creates a directed acyclic graph (DAG) where each node is a target and each edge is a prerequisite relationship.

Make chooses a starting node as either (a) a target requested on the command line, or (b) the first target defined in the makefile.

From there make will walk the graph depth-first, left to right.  So given this makefile:

```
A: B C
B: D E
C: F
E: G
```

make will walk the DAG like this:

```
A -> B -> D -> E -> G -> C -> F
```

Because make builds leaf nodes first, the actual invocation of recipes (assuming all nodes are out of date) will be in this order:

```
D, G, E, B, F, C, A
```

You can prove this to yourself trivially with this simple makefile:

```
A: B C
B: D E
C: F
E: G
A B C D E F G: ; @echo $@
```

So, now how does parallelism come into it?

In a parallel build make creates the same DAG and follows the same algorithm to walk it.  The big difference is what happens when make decides to build a target.  In a non-parallel build make will invoke the recipe and wait for it to end, then go to the next one.

In a parallel build (assuming not infinite jobs) make will first obtain a jobserver token.  If it can't it will sleep waiting for one.  If it can, it invokes the recipe for that target but instead of waiting, it returns to its algorithm and goes to the next node in the DAG, which will be the sibling node.  If there's no sibling we will go back up to the parent and see if *that* has a sibling (make can't build the parent because the child has not completed yet) to build.  Etc. through the DAG.  If it get to the end of the DAG and not everything has been completed, make starts over from the beginning.

Comment: So the mutex protected data structure which handles asynchronicity (and finally produces a fetchable token) is solely confined inside the jobserver, I understand.

Comment: Well, make is not multithreaded so there's actually no mutex or protected data structure for tokens.  Make relies solely on the atomicity of single-byte reads from a pipe to make the jobserver work.  http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/ contains a description although some of the details are incorrect in newer versions of GNU make (which now use pselect()).